# Uploading to AWS EC2 Rstudio instance from a dropbox link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upload, dropbox

Is it possible to read a (tab delimited) file directly into Rstudio on an AWS EC2 instance from a dropbox link?
I have tried a number of ways to do this 
An example dropbox link (sharing via dropbox) would be something like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfgohafsdfvssdgahahd/myfilename.csv?dl=0

Methods I have tried include the below

install.packages("RCurl")

library(RCurl)

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

URL <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfgohafsdfvssdgahahd/myfilename.csv?dl=0"

x <- getURL(URL)

This was unsuccessful, though using the method
install.packages("readr")

library(readr)

x <- read_delim("https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfgohafsdfvssdgahahd/myfilename.csv?dl=0", delim="\t", col_names=TRUE)

gave some interesting output, similar to

> x

Source: local data frame [338 x 1]

(chr)
1                                                                                                                                          window.*goch* = {};
2                                                                                                           window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
3                                                                                                                                                'use strict';
4                                                                                                 for (var elm = event.target; elm; elm = elm.parentElement) {
5                                                                                                                                                if (elm.id &&
6                                                                                                                      window.*goch*.hasOwnProperty(elm.id) &&
7                                                                                                          window.*goch*[elm.id].call(elm, event) === false) {
8                                                                                                                                      event.preventDefault();
9                                                                                                                                                            }
10                                                                                                                                                           }

So something was definitely downloaded, but certainly not as intended.  I am interested in finding out what this downloaded material is and how to access my file.  Thank you

Comment: Just to be specific the Dropbox link provided in the example is a dummy link

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox shared links of the format you gave are "preview" links by default, which are HTML pages, and do not return the file content directly. Instead, you'll need to modify these links, as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

For example, you would turn this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfgohafsdfvssdgahahd/myfilename.csv?dl=0

Into this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfgohafsdfvssdgahahd/myfilename.csv?raw=1

You need to make sure your code follows redirects though.

Comment: Thanks what I thought as well, but for small files <40kb, it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I realised what was going on here.  If someone has a better way to get around this please feel free to add it, but.. The default home directory size for AWS is less than 8-10GB regardless of the size of your instance.  As this as trying to upload to home then there was not enough room.  An experienced linux user would not have fallen into this trap, but hopefully any other windows users new to this who come across this problem will see this.  If you upload into a different drive on the instance then this can be solved.  As the Louis Aslett Rstudio AMI is based in this 8-10GB space then you will have to set your working directory outside this, the home directory.  Not intuitively apparent from Rstudio server interface.  Whilst this is an advanced forum and this is a rookie error I am hoping no one deletes this question as I spent weeks on this before giving up on using dropbox for this and I think someone else will too.